# Invoking an event listener in nunit 3 using C# and Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, events, selenium-webdriver, event-listener, nunit-3.0

I have read and understood how to set up an event listener (I think) for Nunit3 by reading https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Event-Listeners but what I don't understand is how to invoke it.  I understand it needs to be invoked outside the structure I just need a solid example.

EDIT: I cannot find a valid example online after about 3 hours of searching.  Maybe I am not searching the right context or syntax.  Here is what I have tried so far:

***The decleration:***

```
[Extension(EngineVersion="3.4")]
public class MyEventListener : ITestEventListener
{
    OnTestResult(string report){
      ....
    } 
}
```

***The caller:***

```
public class DriverSetup(){

driver = new EventFiringWebDriver FiringDriver;

    public void RegisterHandler(){

        MyEventListener listener = new MyEventListener;
    }
}
```

I can't figure how to attach the handler to the driver as in C# there is no 'register' method like in Java.

Comment: Good point let me edit it.